# Sorting & Matching Comma Separated String Values (PHP / mySQL)

Tags: php, csv, count, matching

I am hoping to get some assistance today regarding the following:

I have two fields in my database table that I need to sort out and match up. On is `staff_id` and the other is `staff_name`.

```
staff_id = "1958324, 5930349, 6802941, 0592854"

staff_name = "John D. Doe, Sammy D'man, Lucy Lane, Jesse J. James"
```

What I need to be able to do is know that the first ID goes with the first name, second ID with second name, etc. All matching values are separated with a comma so it shouldn't be to hard but it is giving me fits.

I'm passing the `staff_id` variable through and I need to be able to query my database and spit out the matching name.

Any help out there?

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<String> getMatchedValues(List<String> staff_id, List<String> staff_name){
    List<String> retVal = new arrayList<String>();
        for(int i=0; i<staff_id.size()){
            retVal.add(staff_id.get(i)+" "+staff_name.get(i));
        }
    return retVal;
}
```